# How to check clickhouse database server live/active connections

Tags: clickhouse

I am trying to check clickhous database(server) active connections from console.
In MYSQL there are many commands Like:

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';
show status like 'Threads_connected';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections";
```

It will return result like this below format.

```
'Threads_connected', '2'
'max_connections', '151'
```

As well as we can from mysql workbench server status menu.
I am checking with below query, but it is not returning any appropriate result.

> SELECT * FROM system.metrics WHERE metric LIKE '%Connection'

```
┌─metric────────────────┬─value─┬
│ TCPConnection         │     1 │
│ MySQLConnection       │     0 │
│ HTTPConnection        │     0 │
│ InterserverConnection │     0 │
│ PostgreSQLConnection  │     0 │
```

> SELECT * FROM system.events LIMIT 1

```
Row 1:
──────
event:       Query
value:       30
description: Number of queries....
```

> SELECT * FROM system.settings WHERE name LIKE 'conn%' LIMIT 1

```
Row 1:
──────
name:        connect_timeout
value:       10
changed:     0
description: Connection timeout if there are no replicas.
min:         ᴺᵁᴸᴸ
max:         ᴺᵁᴸᴸ
readonly:    0
type:        Seconds
```

Please share some idea how can check open session or connection.

Thank you,
Bimal.

Answer (score 1):

The query

```sql
SELECT * FROM system.metrics WHERE metric LIKE '%Connection'
```

is a right query, but look like not all metrics currently calculate properly. You could create an issue on `github` about it.

Comment: But, it always return same vales weather one client its connected or more then one client applications is connected. Like :  TCPConnection  = 1  , MySQLConnection  = 0 ,HTTPConnection  = 0  ,InterserverConnection = 0,   PostgreSQLConnection = 0 .